# Sticky nav slide up not smooth on first scroll. Fine after

Tags: javascript

This is driving me mad and I can't find the cause.
I'm using the following to make my nav slide up on scroll down and back on scroll up.

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-140px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Here's the CSS

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem is that on the first scroll down after page load it just disappears abruptly. It's only on subsequent scrolls that it slides smoothly.

Comment: That's probably because the `top` style is not in the css class, so as far as the transition is concerned, nothing has changed because it is only looking at the class.  Try creating two classes - #navbar.one and #navbar.two (or whatever names make sense), one for each `top` setting as well as the rest of the styles, and change the class in your code instead.

Comment: @HookedHangman in addition to the above comment `don't try to do css's job in javascript`

Comment: I knew it was something simple that I just wasn't seeing. I'm doing this as a way to practice as I learn so this is all very helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It was that I hadn't specified the initial position. I'll definitely be going back to rework it based on the advice given.

Thanks again.